# How To Use PHP/MySQL To Manage Fill Color of SVG?

Tags: php, svg

I have a USA map in SVG format. I need each state to be filled with a color depending on a color hex value stored for the state in a MySQL file that gets populated by users via a PHP form.

To further explain, in my php program that displays the USA map as an SVG, here is my initial code where, for illustrative purposes here only, I have hard-coded the first state, Alaska, to be red:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#map').usmap({
  stateSpecificStyles': { 'AK' : {fill: '#f00'}
},
```

etc, ...repeat for each state...

and what I'd like to do is replace the "fill: '#f00" with the color value stored in the hex color field on the MySQL record for AK.

So, my question is:

How do I pass the color hex value stored in the MySQL record for a state to the SVG object for that state and thus be able to apply the fill color for it?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Why not store the colors for each of the states in the DB, and then use the JSON as an object within the `usmap` function?

Comment: @eithed: I understand that each key in the JSON object would be a state abbreviation (e.g., 'AK'), but how exactly do I assign the state's MySQL color value to it's associated JSON value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are missing some quotes around the colour.  Instead of:

```
$('#map').usmap({ 'stateSpecificStyles': { 'AK' : {fill: <?php echo '#f00'; ?>} } });
```

try:

```
$('#map').usmap({ 'stateSpecificStyles': { 'AK' : {fill: '<?php echo '#f00'; ?>'} } });
```

Comment: @BigBadBaboom: yes, that was it, forgot those single quotes! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How is the SVG being included?  Is it inlined, or embedded via an `<image>` or `<object>`?   The answer will affect the solution.

Assuming for the moment it is inlined, here is how I would do it.

Give each of the states an id.  Eg.

```
<g id="AK"> ... </g>
```

Then you can either add CSS styles (added in your PHP script):

```
#AK {fill: red;}
```

or you could set it directly using JS (eg. read as JSON and applied at onLoad):

```
document.getElementById("AK").style.fill = "red";
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using inline SVG and have set it up so that I can manually tweak the colors of each state. What I do not yet understand is how to dynamically get the color code from the database and apply it to either of the 2 methods (CSS or JS). How do I set up a PHP loop to get the value from the color field and thus apply it to CSS or JS? In other words, how would I say: document.getElementById("AK").style.fill = <?php echo $stateColor; ?>

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying you don't know how to get it from the database?  Or you don't know how to do a loop in PHP?  Or you don't know how to add JavaScript to your HTML output?

Comment: I know how to use PHP to set up loops and extract data. What I do not know is how to get the values I extract into my JavaScript code so that each state knows what color to be filled with. In other words, this sample code does not work but shows what I am trying to do to get the state of Alaska to be filled with the color red:     $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#map').usmap({
      'stateSpecificStyles': {
         'AK' : {fill: <?php echo '#f00'; ?>}
  },

Comment: Ah. I have twigged now.  You are using a jQuery plugin called "usmap".  I hadn't heard of that and it wasn't so obvious from your question.